# Unwrap XPCNativeWrapper object in Firefox  versions < 3.6.2

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, wrapper

Is there a way to unwrap an `XPCNativeWrapper` object in early versions of Firefox (before version 3.6.2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing the wrapper's `wrappedJSObject` property is functionally equivalent whenever the object passed to `XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap` is an `XPCNativeWrapper`. For example, assuming you know your window is a wrapped object, then the following is "true":

```
XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap(window) === window.wrappedJSObject // => true
```

`XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap` is safer when you don't know for sure that you're dealing with a wrapped object. For example, the following is "true":

```
var test = [1, 2, 3];
XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap(test) === test // => true
```

...but this is "false" (when using the same array):

```
XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap(test) === test.wrappedJSObject // false
```